# Copy url in link to webform

Tags: hooks

I would like to know if it is possible to set up a link on a node to open a webform and copy the url from the node where the link sits to a field in the webform when it opens. If not, maybe copy some text in the link to the webform?

Comment: Is the webform on the same page as the node? In other words do you need the url  for the page the webform is on? Or do you need a url that refers to a node elsewhere?

Comment: the link to the webform would be on a node. when you click the link it would open a new page/webform. I would like the url from the previous page (where the link was clicked) to be populated into a field in the new webform page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that it needed
    **%get[product_url]**
instead of
    **[current-page:query:product_url]**
in the webform field. It is now working.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way to do it would be to pass the path in a GET variable and use a token.

So on your node page edit the webform link to include the path like so

```
<a href="/link/to/webform?yoururl=theurlyoureon">Webform link</a>
```

Then on your webform for that textfield use [current-page:query:yoururl] as your default value.

Obviously replace yoururl with whatever you want to name the variable.

Comment: my link on the node is:   <a class="btn-orange" href="/demo-request-em?product_url=/em/rmc-ln-ultra-cryosectioning-system" target="_blank"> I have created a field in the separate webform page and put in the default value of: [current-page:query:product_url]. When I click on the link it opens the webform and in the new field it just shows the default value in text of: [current-page:query:product_url]. I guess user error some description? Sorry, not sure how the formatting works on here

Comment: What version of Drupal and webform are you using?

Comment: Drupal 7.58 & Webform 7.x-3.27

Comment: Do you have the token module installed?

Comment: Yes, Version: 7.x-1.7